# What are the Options in Undeploying Etherpad?

Tags: cygwin, etherpad

Are there "clean" ways of undeploying Etherpad on a (Windows Server 2003) server? Right now, I just use ctrl+c on the cygwin console or end the process on the Task Manager. I don't want to use TASKKILL /fi "imagename eq cmd*" since it can end other cmd processes as well. I plan to make a script to automate deployment and undeployment of Etherpad.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Etherpad was built to run on unix, and when you do a clean shutdown you'll notice a few lines about saving to disk etc being output.
You can make your .cmd or .bat script stay open after it finishes running, or add a line
pause
at the end of the script, and then you'll see if Ctrl-C causes a clean shutdown.

If you want to automate the shutdown, you'll need to find a windows software that can send the appropriate signals. Windows supposednly has some posix compatibility built in, so there's a fair chance you can find both the needed signal and some free/shareware to send the signal.

If this works out, maybe you could blog about your solution and/or add a wikipage on github.com/ether/pad/wiki
Otherwise, contact the etherpad team via github.com/ether/pad/issues and ask for a windows-compatible clean shutdown feature.